# Enable phpmyadmin in bitnami lamp stack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

Failed to create tunnel using below command

```
sh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i /Users/josh/work/private.pem bitnami@ip-10-65-174-121
```

Why this won't work? I'm on mac and couldn't enable phpmyadmin. I've also tried `sh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i /Users/josh/work/private.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-110-244-106.compute-1.amazonaws_example.com`

nothing work :(

Comment: +1: it is also my question, i use 
`ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 bitnami@192.168.1.123` due to [bitnami official wiki](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_AMP_Stacks) but couldn't access `phpmyadmin` via chrome. Please make an answer if you find out any solution.

Comment: I found the answer. above lines are answer so i complete my answer in `Answer` section. follow there.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [bitnami official wiki](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/phpMyAdmin_and_phpPgAdmin?utm_source=bitnami&utm_medium=virtualmachine&utm_campaign=Virtual%2BMachine) we should make a `PuTTY` connection to virtual lamp stack server.
I suppose your virtual server address is `192.168.1.123` , then you should make the putty link to this address and before connect you should set these fields in 
`PuTTY Configuration Panel`:
Go to `Connection>SSH>Tunnels` and set `Source Port` to `8888` and `Destination` to `localhost:80` then press `add` and apply then go to session and save to this connection, then open the connection and input username and password.
 Connection MUST be open during use of `phpmyadmin` and you can access it from your browser with `http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin/`.
By the way, for first login you could use `root` as username and your password.